# fullcalendar eventsources no longer display events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

Just updated my fullcalendar to 1.6.3 and jQuery to 1.10.2
Suddenly my calendar no longer shows events from "eventSources".
I cant find anything in the documentation that states that anything needs to be changed.
To isolate the problem I have created a very small test example so that I'm sure that no 3rd party plugin og CSS or anything is responsible.

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullcalendar.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#kalender').fullCalendar(
            {
                eventSources: ['testfeed.php'] 
                //testfeed.php returns exactly: [{title: 'test1', start: '2013-08-15'},{title: 'test2', start: '2013-08-16'}]

                // events: [{title: 'test1', start: '2013-08-15'},{title: 'test2', start: '2013-08-16'}]
            });  
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="kalender"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

This example doesn't work even though my "testfeed.php" returns exactly the same json code as if I put it directly into the "events" property. If I comment out the "eventSources" line and uncomment the "events" line, then everything is fine. But I need to use the eventsources as I did before the update. What am I missing? This is driving med insane :)

Thanks in advance for all your input!

Kind regards

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone else that comes here, the answer for me was to change my json source to look like this (i.e. just the array, not the 'events:' wrapper) :

```
[{"title":"new one due 7 Oct","start":"2015-10-07","end":"2015-10-08","allDay":true}]
```

and then call with the url option like:

```
eventSources: [
      {
        url: '/someurl'
      }
    ]
```